# How can I add custom field to collection?

Tags: magento2

I have a output structure of collection like this:

[image]

I need such a structure filled with a specific value:

[image]

How do I achieve this?

Comment: is Column4 a virtual Field?

Comment: Yes, this column is virtual

Answer (score 1):

I did it with the addition 'columns':

`$subject->getCollection()->getSelect()->columns(['Column 4' => '(\'a1\')']);`

Comment: You got the answer, yourself. very good!